# woocommerce added fee is not calculating always 0 neather total price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have 2 functions. One is to calculate fee (here  is part from it that is responsible for calculating fee and saving it into global variable):

```
function pre_checkout()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $section2 ='';
    $section3 ='';
    $section2 = sanitize_text_field($_POST["user_data"]["section2"]);
    $section3 = sanitize_text_field($_POST["user_data"]["section3"]);
    $how_many_months = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_POST["user_data"]["section1"]);
    $boxToFind = '';
    if(($section2 == 'toy_yes') || ($section2 == 'toy_no'))
    {
        $boxToFind = sanitize_text_field($_POST["user_data"]["section1"]);
    }
    else{
        $boxToFind = sanitize_text_field($_POST["user_data"]["section1"].$_POST["user_data"]["section2"]);
    }
    WC()->cart->empty_cart(true);
    $boxesLookupTable = array(
            //susbscriptions
     'small1month'=>'112',
    'medium1month'=>'113',
    'large1month'=>'114',
    'small6month'=>'115',
    'medium6month'=>'116',
    'large6month'=>'117',
    'small12month'=>'118',
    'medium12month'=>'119',
    'large12month'=>'120',
        //gifts
    'gift1month'=>'133',
    'gift3month'=>'134',
    'gift6month' =>'135',
    'gift12month' =>'136'
    );
    $productId = $boxesLookupTable[$boxToFind];
//    echo $productId;
    //check if product already in cart
    // if no products in cart, add it
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart($productId,1);
    if($section2 === "toy_yes"){
        $product = wc_get_product($productId);
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $toy_price = 4.99;
        unset($_COOKIE['product_price_with_toy']);
        setcookie('product_price_with_toy',$toy_price*$how_many_months,time() + (86400 * 30),"/");
    //  WC_Cart::add_fee( 'Gift Fee ', $product_price_with_toy,false, false );
        /* "gift"; */
    }
    if($section3 === "toy_yes"){
        $how_many_months = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_POST["user_data"]["section2"]);
        $product = wc_get_product($productId);
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $toy_price = 4.99;
        unset($_SESSION['product_price_with_toy']);
        $_SESSION['product_price_with_toy']  = $price + $toy_price;
        unset($_COOKIE['product_price_with_toy']);
        setcookie('product_price_with_toy',$how_many_months * $toy_price,time() + (86400 * 30),"/");
    //    WC_Cart::add_fee( 'Gift Fee ', $product_price_with_toy,false, false );
        /*"subscription"; */
    };
    $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_url = wc_get_cart_url();
    $checkout_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    foreach($items as $item => $values) {
        $_product = $values['data']->post;
    ?>
    <div class="dropdown-cart-wrap">
        <div class="dropdown-cart-left">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $values['product_id'], 'thumbnail' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-cart-right">
            <h5><?php echo $_product->post_title; ?></h5>
            <p><strong>Quantity:</strong>
               <?php $product = wc_get_product($productId);
                woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'min_value' => 1, 'max_value' => $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity() ) );
                ?></p>
            <?php global $woocommerce;
            $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
            $price = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_regular_price', true);
            $sale = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_sale_price', true);
            ?>
            <?php if($sale) { ?>
                <p class="price"><strong>Price:</strong> <del><?php echo $currency; echo $price; ?></del> <?php echo $currency; echo $sale; ?></p>
            <?php } elseif($price) { ?>
                <p class="price"><strong>Price:</strong> <?php echo $currency; echo $price; ?></p>
            <?php }
            ?>
            <div class="dropdown-cart-right dropdown-checkout-link">
                <a class="checkout-submit checkout green-btn text-center" href="#">Order</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<?php }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_pre_checkout','pre_checkout');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pre_checkout', 'pre_checkout');
```

Next i have woocommerce action:

```
function add_cart_fee() {
    $chuj = $GLOBALS['product_price_with_toy'];
    WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Extra Gift Fee', 'woocommerce'),$chuj );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_cart_fee' );
```

And basicaly toy fee is always 0 when im using session, global variables - only through cookies is passing values to action - i dont understand  why woocommerce / wordpress is wiping global value  that ive  set inside my calculation function. Or maybe someone know how to update the total price with using hooks and actions,  that would be even better than using fee field.

[image: fee for gift product]
[image: fee for subscription type product]

Comment: If section2 condition is missing a variable $how_many_months. Please declare how it comes about.

Comment: Hi.  variable $how_many_months  exist  above  this condition:  $how_many_months = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_POST["user_data"]["section1"]);

Comment: @KrzysztofKoch Your code is incomplete: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other reader".*

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, i have added  full function. This function works only  with cookies.